# LMS with CiviCRM/drupal integration?

Tags: drupal

Looking for recommendations on Learning Management Systems (LMS) that work with drupal/CiviCRM. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. This platform is for questions that have correct answers and doesn't work for opinion based answers. Can you edit your question with what what research you have done and what you might be stuck on or reword so that a correct answer can be given? You may want to start with seeing how you can integrate an LMS with Drupal first and then look into how you can use CiviCRM with that.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to answer your question without more details about what KIND of integration you're looking for, but I can give two answers:

- If you're looking for a Learning Record Store (LRS), a [native Drupal LRS](https://www.drupal.org/project/tincan_lrs) exists, and CiviCRM integration for it exists too.
- Some integration with Moodle exists via [CiviMoodle](https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.civimoodle) - you can register someone for a CiviCRM event, and they're signed up for one or more corresponding events  in Moodle (with user creation if necessary).
- There's also some [custom integration](https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.civimoodle.afabc) for pulling grades back into CiviCRM from Moodle, but would need some love from a developer to fit someone's situation.

Answer (score 0):

Agree that the question is pretty vague. We have delivered an LMS for a client who does professional development / training that is built purely with Webforms and CiviCRM Activities. Obviously this may not stretch to very complex scenarios, hence it is worth articulating exactly what outcomes you require.